# (#100) "Subject should be a page account" error when trying to publish video to facebook page

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make an application that able to publish video to a Facebook page. I obtain list of available pages via /me/account request and get correct response:

```
[{
  "access_token":"XXX",
  "category":"Music Video",
  "category_list":[{"id":"1207","name":"Music Video"}],
  "name":"My mighty musical page",
  "id":"XXX",
  "tasks":["ANALYZE","ADVERTISE","MODERATE","CREATE_CONTENT","MANAGE"]
}]
```

after this I take the "id" value and send request to start live video, using the id value as page-id in the link:

> {Request:  accessToken: 
>       {AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[manage_pages, publish_video, publish_pages, user_videos, public_profile,
>   pages_show_list, publish_to_groups, groups_access_member_info,
>   email]}, 
>       **graphPath: /XXX/live_videos**, 
>       graphObject: null, 
>       httpMethod: POST, 
>       parameters: Bundle[{privacy={"value":"EVERYONE"}}]
>       }

As a result I receive the following error:

> {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: -1, errorType:
>   OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) Subject should be a page account}
>   /APP: [FacebookFramework] Attempt to start streaming to
>   Facebook returned the error: code 100, message: (#100) Subject should
>   be a page account
>       {FacebookServiceException: httpResponseCode: 400, facebookErrorCode: 100, facebookErrorType: OAuthException, message:
>   (#100) Subject should be a page account}

that actually describes nothing about what goes wrong. I have all required permissions. I am creator of the page and have admin rights. I have no idea where can I find this "correct id". Did I miss something important?

PS. Also I use similar code to post to a group and it works ok.

Comment: are you using a page token?

Comment: No. I receive it as a string, but did not find a way push it into start streaming request.

Comment: As described in documentaiton  `new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{page-id}/live_videos",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you were right, the problem was that I did not pass correct token when tried to start streaming. Correct token is received with /me/account response. I created token the following way

```
        final AccessToken currentToken = getCurrentAccessToken();
        new AccessToken (
            "XXX", //custom token string here
            currentToken.getApplicationId(),
            currentToken.getUserId(),
            currentToken.getPermissions(),
            currentToken.getDeclinedPermissions(),
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
        );
```

and it works well with this new token